# How to interpret the received data in C++ when using gSoap?

Tags: c++, service, gsoap

I have implemented a service in C++ using **gSoap**. I have created it from a **multiple existing WSDL files**.

And now I need to give a definition to every virtual method of the service.

Let's take a look at one generated method declaration in the file soapMyServiceService.h:

```
///
/// Service operations (you should define these):
/// Note: compile with -DWITH_PURE_VIRTUAL for pure virtual methods
///

/// Web service operation 'Initialize' (returns error code or SOAP_OK)

virtual int Initialize(_ns5__Initialize *ns5__Initialize, _ns5__InitializeResponse *ns5__InitializeResponse);
```

Actually, I was expecting to get :

```
virtial string Initialize(int var_a , int var_b , string var_c);
```

But now, I need to implement it what I got generated and return the SOAP code :

```
int MyService::Initialize(_ns5__Initialize *ns5__Initialize, _ns5__InitializeResponse *ns5__InitializeResponse)
{
    // HOW can I get here the received values for that I can able to implement my logic?
    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

How can I get the received values ( the values sent by the client for var_a, var_b, and var_c) and then set for him the returned for the string and in the same time return the error code...

**How do you normally implement the logic of the services?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service method implementation MyService::Initialize(_ns5__Initialize *ns5__Initialize,  _ns5__InitializeResponse *ns5__InitializeResponse)
the last argument is the response argument all the rest are input argument, here you have only one input parameter that is of type _ns5__Initialize which probably wud be a structure, if you access its member, you will get all the input parameters of the request.

Comment: Effectively you are right. The members of ns5_Initialize are var_a, var_b, var_c but I guess there is a problem somewhere. Because it's not me who defined the above structure, it was generated. It would have been better if there was a way to have the right arguments...

Comment: Yes, it is generated via your wsdl, wsdl define your method parameters their type, name. etc

Comment: Can you tell me the exact WSDL tag to check? Thank you a lot!